# Angular.js $scope and dom element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

How does angular keep track of which $scope is related to which element? I have a few theories:

1. angular element keeps scope object as property
2. angular saves each scope in cache with the relationship with element
3. angular searches each ng-scope, and magically find element

For example, I have an element with $scope, and I want to change dom hierarchy  of this element (moving to outside of the outer controller). How is scope  affected by this action?

Comment: Provide more specifics about what you are trying to do. If you move an element that is inside an `ng-repeat` for example angular won't know about it unless you move the data also. Current question is too broad without some context. This could be an `X-Y problem` where you should be considering manipulating your model data instead

Comment: in link stage , scope inheritance mimics the dom hiearchy . I have a directive inside ng-controller div (div a) , and I move this directive to (div a) sibling ng-controller (div b). It is clear that I break dom hierachy by changing directive position.So how scope is affected by this action, scope hiearchy is also break base on dom hiearchy.

Comment: if you want help provide a code example

Comment: I am testing the inner functionality of angularjs.  There is no a big stuff here. I just want to understand where $scope is save and how angular understand this specific dom is related with specific $scope object

Answer (score 1):

If you have an angular app, and your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="OuterController">
    ...
    <div ng-controller="InnerController">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <span>An Element</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you move the `<span>` out of the `#wrapper` div, it's still within the context of both `OuterController` and `InnerController`. However, if you move it up to where the `...` is, only the `OuterController`'s context applies.

Each controller has its own context, and that context extends down into all child-elements recursively, even if a new controller is present, at which point, both controllers are in-scope.

This is true whether the element is moved dynamically with Javascript or otherwise. Angular keeps track of most context internally.

Comment: I would elaborate on how those controllers have different scopes... Just in case.

Comment: Can you explain , where $scope object is saved , and how angular understand which specific scope is related with specific dom object